# Use text color as tab indicator via sherlock - How to?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

I want to achieve a custom styled tab indicator for my app but I can't find how to do it, all I found was how to change style in the regular tab style provided by SherlockFragments.

Here's what I want to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08P19.jpg - Create a thin tab indicator which changes the color of the tab's name to indicate the current tab.

Could someone please help me with it? Codes, tutorials, tips, everything would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library, there is a demo app on the play store

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at ActionBarCompat, instead of ActionBarSherlock, for future maintainability.

Either way, you might want to check out the [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) for more ideas and help on themes... you can set your own colors for various elements of your theme, and download it as one zip.